# string remove and update

Tags: c++, c++20

Trying to remove and replace in string with single loop.
For Example :

Input :  "the-new-year"

with my code

```
std::string convert(std::string text) {
    std::string val;
    auto index{ 0 };
    for (auto x : text)
    { 
        if (x != '-')
        {
            val.push_back(x);
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            val.push_back(std::toupper(text[index+1]));
            index++;
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

call :`convert("the-new-year");`

Expected output : "theNewYear"

Getting result : "theNnewYyear" // Error extra character still there

Any suggestions using any STL algo ?

Comment: Look at `std::remove`

Comment: I'd use a boolean: `if x == '-' then upperCaseNext = true; else { if upperCaseNext then { x = toupper(x); } val.push_back(x); upperCaseNext = false; }` is the approximate pseudocode. Handles "-foo--bar-" and other edge cases, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do it in two steps:

First capitalize the first letter after a dash. Use a plain iterator or index for loop for this:

```
std::string val = text;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < val.length(); ++i)
{
    if (i > 0 && val[i - 1] == '-')
    {
        val[i] = std::toupper(val[i]);
    }
}
```

Then using [the erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) use [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [the string `erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) functions to remove the dashes:

```
val.erase(std::remove(begin(val), end(val), '-'), end(val));
```

Comment: As per the link provided For C++20
As of C++20, the free functions std::erase and std::erase_if are provided for STL containers. These convenience functions can be used to perform correct erasure of elements without requiring the programmer to explicitly use the erase-remove idiom.

Comment: @HariomSingh Well that will make the second step a little easier at least. :)

Comment: If you start at `std::size_t i = 1;` you can remove the additional branch condition `i>0`. Although the compiler *might* also catch that.